# Asynchronous webservice in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, web-services

How can I set up an asynchronous web service in asp.net?

I want to call a webservice to post some data to a database, but I don't care if the response failed or succeeded.

I can use .net 2.0 or 3.5 only and it can be in vb or c#.

Comment: I think you mean "asynchronous".

Comment: Why do you want it to be asynchronous? Is it because calling a simple web-service is not fast enough for you?

Comment: I want to log things but I don't want what I'm doing to slow down the user's experience. So if this webservice craps out or is slow for some reason, I want the main web application to keep trucking along. So if that is asynchronous or synchronous, I'd like to do that.

Comment: Asynchronous is definitely what you want then. I've edited your post to reflect your intent.

Comment: Are you calling the web service server side or client side through javascript?

Comment: I want to call it on the server side.

Comment: @Hemant, was that a serious comment? It's almost always better to write code to be asynchronous and just use up a completion port while waiting for response rather than taking up a thread that's just waiting.  C# would be a better language if it didn't even have synchronous I/O support and forced everyone to use async calls.

Comment: @Sam: C# doesn't have I/O. What do you mean?

Comment: @John Saunders, what I said is if C# didn't have **synchronous** I/O it would be better off.  The asynchronous pattern provides for much better resource utilization and there are other languages that provide only asynchronous I/O api's which often take getting used to but provide better results.  I read a quote from someone much more authoritative than me saying the same thing, but I tried and couldn't find it, so I have to leave it as just my opinion.

Comment: @Sam: it has **no** I/O. What "I/O" are you referring to?

Comment: @John Saunders, I'm talking about all of the API's that call out for potentially long running procedures and usually provide synchronous and asynchronous (Begin/End) variations.  These include things like Sockets, Web Services, File operations, basically everything commonly referred to as "I/O" or "Input/Output".  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I/o

Comment: @Sam: none of that is part of C#!!!

Comment: @John Saunders, perhaps you're referring to the fact that I keep saying C# when I really mean the .NET?

Comment: @John Saunders, you're right, but I'm curious, when was the last time you programmed in C# without using the .NET framework?

Comment: @Samuel: better question: when was the last time I programmed in VB.NET? Using more than one .NET language, and programming the same framework, makes it very clear the distinction between C# and .NET. VB.NET _does_ have I/O BTW, at least it does if they've kept the old BASIC I/O statements.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you create the service reference in visual studio click the "Advanced..." button and check off "Generate asynchronous operations".  Then you'll have the option to make asynchronous calls against the web service.

Here's a sample of both a synchronous and the same asynchronous call to a public web service.

```
// http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx?wsdl
using(var wf = new WeatherForecasts.WeatherSoapClient())
{
    // example synchronous call
    wf.GetCityForecastByZIP("20850");

    // example asynchronous call
    wf.BeginGetCityForecastByZIP("20850", result => wf.EndGetCityForecastByZIP(result), null);
}
```

It might be tempting to just call `BeginXxx` and not do anything with the result since you don't care about it.  You'll actually leak resources though.  It's important that every `BeginXxx` call is matched with a corresponding `EndXxx` call.

Even though you have a callback that calls `EndXxx`, this is triggered on a thread pool thread and the original thread that called `BeginXxx` is free to finish as soon as the `BeginXxx` call is done (it doesn't wait for the response).

Comment: [This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480516.aspx) had a good breakdown of how to create the methods you mentioned above. Posted by @gbvb

Answer (score 2):

Webservices are usually for Request/Response style services. That said, there is a simple mechanism to do async implementation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480516.aspx. There are ways to just do fire and forget webservices as well: http://blogs.x2line.com/al/archive/2007/05/21/3108.aspx using [OneWay](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soapdocumentmethodattribute.oneway.aspx) attribute on SoapDocumentMethod .

Comment: This is good information but it refers to implementing an async web service.  guanome asked about calling a web service asynchronously.

Comment: got it. I was seeing it from the web service side. I guess 4 beers is one too many to answer on stackoverflow. :)

Comment: @gbvb, hold onto that answer, I'm sure the right question will come along.  :-)

Comment: @Samuel Neff What's the difference in creating an async web service and calling a web service asynchronously?

Comment: @gbvb, the msdn article helped a lot. THANKS!

Comment: @guanome, the difference between consuming an async web service and consuming one is exactly the same as comparing a web browser to a web server. A web service can be consumed by a client either synchronously or asynchronously and the client code will either block and wait for a response or it will use a callback to handle the redponse. It's common and pretty much always better to consume a web servic asynchronously.

Comment: Implementing a web service asynchronously is far less common and not always beneficial. The server side of a web service performs some actions and returns a result. With the techniques mentioned above the actions can be broken up into parts which is helpful if the service in turn waits on other resources, like a long db call, another web service call. Async web services are also ideally suited for implementing long polling.

Comment: Also note that when consuming web services, some environments like .NET, offer both sync and async calls, but others like JavaScript only offer async and even others like ColdFusion only offer sync calls.

Comment: @Sam: implementing the service asynchronously can help scalability by not taking up worker threads waiting around for database or other slow operations.

Comment: The second link is now dead

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't sound like there is any reason that the web service has to be synchronous.  Go async for maximum performance, especially if some of the tasks may be long running.

Comment: Will the page this is calling the web service have to wait on a response from the web service?

Comment: It sounds like what you want is an asynchronous http request (AJAX).  Look up XmlHttpRequest.  jQuery has a good API that can help you.  If you use Ajax, your page will not have to wait on a response from the webservice.

Comment: I've used the jquery ajax method before, but I need to be able to call the web service from the server side.

Comment: Can I use XmlHttpRequest on the server side?

Comment: @Smartcaveman, this answer, or more specifically the follow on vomments, really doesn't answer the question. Guanome is asking how to call a web service asynchronoudly from a c# client. Answers with XmlHttpRequest and jQuery do not fit here.

Comment: I agree.  However, my answer did not say to use XmlHttpRequest or jQuery.  His follow up question asked how to prevent a webpage from relying on a server response for continued use of the webpage.  I interpret that to mean that he wants the user to be able to continue to use the page while he sends a request to the server.  This means he wants to send a request without waiting for the page post back.  So, the answer to that second question does call for the use of Ajax.